# Criação de um mailClient

Tags: c#, .net

Estou em um projeto o qual preciso desenvolver um Cliente de email, no entanto estou um tanto quanto perdido quanto a isso, então.

Preciso usar o protocolo IMAP (estudei a fundo o RFC dele) e a linguagem C#, mas posso também usar Java. Alguém tem algum caminho, lista de requisitos, ou alguma experiencia que possa me passar para ajudar com esse projeto?

Será algo bem simplificado se comparado ao Thunderbird. Programo razoavelmente bem no entanto sou iniciante, como posso dar o ponta-pé inicial nesse projeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para IMAP, você pode tentar:

**MailSystem.NET** 
http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/reading-mails-using-imap-and-mailsystem-net/

Ou o **aenetmail** 
https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail

ver um exemplo com o protocolo neste cliente simples para IMAP
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-IMAP-CLIENT-b249d2e6

Comment: Nossa obrigado eu estava procurando um exemplo a um tempão! passarei a madrugada dando uma baseada nele. Obrigado! Até porque ainda não sei por onde começar ao certo, tenho 2 dias para entregar, já aprendi 90% da sintaxe de C# foi bem tranquilo. Agora é só modelar msm.

Answer (score 2):

Existem duas formas.

Se você abrir uma conexão telnet com um servidor de email, você poderá passar os comandos do protocolo IMAP via prompt. Experimente, é divertido! E se é possível com Telnet, é possível com... [Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx)!

WCF não é bem minha especialidade, mas você pode usar ao invés dos sockets. Tenho certeza que fica mais fácil ainda.

A outra forma é dar uma olhada em projetos open source pra implementar IMAP em .NET (nativamente, o Framework só tem classes pra trabalhar com SMTP). Dá uma pesquisada aí. Vou deixar só uma sugestão: [MailSystem.NET](https://github.com/pmengal/MailSystem.NET).

Comment: Opa vou dar uma olhada aqui, Obrigado vou tentar fazer usando uma GUI simplificada o Visual ajuda muito na criação dela. E obrigado pela sugestão.